# proxy_pass a specific query string

Tags: nginx

I need to create a nginx proxy pass which currently breaks my head. From what I see there's very less resources about that problem, online. So I hope somebody is willing to help me out, here.

So I'm having an URI like this:

```
/files/videos/12/play.mov?query1=34&query2=56&query3=78
```

and I want it to be proxy passed to this destination:

```
http://127.0.0.1:25123/stream/56
```

So I want the argument of **query2** to be inserted after **/stream/**

Could anybody please give me a tip how to do this?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
location /files/videos/12/ {
    if ($args ~* "/?query1=[0-9]+&query2=[0-9]+&query3=[0-9]+") {
        rewrite ^ http://127.0.0.1:25123/stream/$arg_query2? last;
    }
}
```

so for proxy_pass maybe:

```
location ~* /files/videos/12/play\.mov\?query1=[0-9]+&query2=([0-9]+)&query3=[0-9]+ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:25123/stream/$1
}
```

It takes the stuff in `()` as Variable and they are numbered from left to right

test with `curl -i`

Comment: thank you very much! But as this is a small webapp sitting behind nginx, rewrite doesn't work here, does it? So it is only reachable via nginx, not by the clients.
Does your approach also works with proxy_pass?